# Binary Operator >= (and <) cannot be applied to operands of types String and Int // Swift

Tags: swift

I am currently working on an assignment for my Swift class at school that takes an array of class grades and sends them through loops. I have two loops running, and I thought that I read the instructions correctly, but I am getting two errors:

**62:11: Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'**

**54:27: Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type '[String : Int]' and 'Int'**

I don't know why I'm getting these errors.

My Code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

 // Create an array that contains a list of courses that you are taking this semester. Print the array.

var listOfCourses: [String] = ["Coding Topics", "Intro to Video Production", "New Testament", "Spiritual Formation in Ministry", "Systematic Theology"]
print(listOfCourses)

// Drop this coding class from the array by targeting its index position and assign the dropped class to a variable. Remember that index counting starts at zero. Using the variable you just created, print a statement that says, "You have dropped __" with the name of the dropped class.

var droppedCoding = listOfCourses.remove(at: 0)
print("You just dropped your \(droppedCoding) class.")

// Add the dropped class back to the end of the array by using the variable you just created.

listOfCourses.append(droppedCoding)
print(listOfCourses)

// Using the count method on the array, print a statment that says, "I am taking __ courses this semester."

listOfCourses.count
print("I'm taking \(listOfCourses.count) classes this semester.")

// Create an array of courses that you took last semester.

var classesITook: [String] = ["Art History Survey 1", "Old Testament", "Hermeneutics", "Family & Childrens Ministry", "Computer Information Systems"]
print(classesITook)

// Create an array that combines the courses from your last two semesters (an array of arrays). Print the new combined array.

var combinedClassSchedule = listOfCourses + classesITook
print(combinedClassSchedule)

// Create a dictionary of assignments and grades from any of your current courses that contains at least four items. Though there's a way to set up a dictionary so you can leave values blank (by using optionals, which we'll get to in a future class), for now just enter assignments for which you've received a grade. Each of your assignments will need to have a unique name, so you may need to add the course code to the beginning of some, e.g. ABC101 Midterm, ABC102 Midterm.

var vidProductionGrades = ["COM251 QUIZ 1": 65, "COM251 Partner Interview": 96, "COM251 Editing Tutorial": 100, "COM251 QUIZ 2": 90, "COM251 Final Exam": 100]

// Update the grade for the second assignment in your list and add five points to it. Assign the previous grade to a variable and print, "Your old grade was __, and your new grade is __." Your print statement should use variables rather than pluging the numbers in directly.

let oldGradeValue = vidProductionGrades["COM251 Partner Interview"] = 96 // <- I can't figure out how to have the old value and the updated new value.
if let newGradeValue = vidProductionGrades.updateValue(101, forKey: "COM251 Partner Interview") {
    print("Your old grade was \(oldGradeValue) and your new grade is \(newGradeValue).")
}

//  Using a for loop on the first array of courses you created, print a statement for each of your courses that says, "I am taking __ this semester."

for course in listOfCourses {
    print("I am taking \(course) this semester.")
}

//  Using a while loop, print the first three graded assignments with their grades. "For __, I earned __"

while vidProductionGrades < 3 { //<-- How to do I loop through the keys and values?
    print("For \(vidProductionGrades), I earned \(vidProductionGrades).")
}

 // Modify your assignment grades dictionary so that you have at least one grade lower than 90 and at least one higher. Now create a loop with the control flow method that will only print out the first grade it finds that is higher or equal to 90. You can use the same wording as the previous loop. This will be the grade you tell your parents about.

let grade1 = vidProductionGrades.updateValue(95, forKey: "COM251 Final Exam")
let grade2 = vidProductionGrades.updateValue(89, forKey: "COM251 Partner Interview")
if grade1 >= 90 {
    print(grade1)
}
```

Comment: The error say that in the first comparison, the operands are of different types: `Int?` and `Int`. If you're sure of the first operand, you can force unwrap it: `(Int?)!  >= Int`. The second error looks to be a comparison between elements in a dictionary compared to an `Int`. Are you trying to get the integer value from a string key and then do the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

The following line is incorrect in the sense of assigning elements into the dictionary:

```
let oldGradeValue = vidProductionGrades["COM251 Partner Interview"] = 96
```

What you want to do is first see if there's an element in the dictionary with the key **COM251 Parter Interview**, and assign it to a variable.

```
let oldGradeValue:Int? = vidProductionGrades["COM251 Partner Interview"]
```

Notice the type as an `Int?` since there could be the possibility that the element with that key does not exists.

To assign the new grade, you do:

```
vidProductionGrades["COM251 Partner Interview"] = 96
```

This either updates the existing grade for that key, or if it's new, it becomes added to the dictionary.

The following code produces an error related to what has been done above.

```
let grade1 = vidProductionGrades.updateValue(95, forKey: "COM251 Final Exam")
let grade2 = vidProductionGrades.updateValue(89, forKey: "COM251 Partner Interview")
if grade1 >= 90 {
    print(grade1)
}
```

The method `updateValue` returns the value that was replaced or `nil` if that new element was added. This causes the comparison error `grade1 >= 90` if the key **COM251 Parter Interview** did not originally exist in the dictionary. This means that `grade1` is of type `Int?`. This can  be resolved by doing:

```
if let previousGrade = grade1 {
    if previousGrade > 90 {
        print(previousGrade)
    }
}
```

If `grade1` is not `nil`, only then will it show the previous grade if it's greater than 90.